# Figure from PDF is always at new page

Tags: floats, pdf

I have a figure in pdf file, which I want to include to my latex file. In the PDF file is only one figure, nothing else. This is code, how I iclude it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\hypersetup{
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
    }

\author{Jozef Mrkvicka}
\title{Lorem Ipsum \\ (FF-FFF) }

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{logo.pdf} 
    \end{figure}

    \newpage
    \section{Introduction}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that figure is always on new blank page, but I want it in the first page under title. Could someone help me, how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using the `float` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Does your title page actually have enough room for the included PDF?

Comment: OK, I edited first post and I add complete source. Yes I think there is enough place for it.

Comment: Can you make `logo.pdf` available for download from somewhere? (Alternatively replace the `\includegraphics` with a `\rule` with the same dimensions.)

Comment: Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/exsi0r43xb2aetz/logo.pdf

Comment: Perhaps there is a `\clearpage` in `\maketitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Removed the float environment**

How about this.

We use the `trim` and `clip` to cut out the logo from the PDF to a usable size. Then, we rescale a bit so it doesn't fill the whole page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\hypersetup{
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
    }

\author{Jozef Mrkvicka}
\title{Lorem Ipsum \\ (FF-FFF) }

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[trim=240 370 250 370 , width=0.3\textwidth]{logo.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

gives us the following

[image]

Comment: Why `figure`? A `center` environment will do better. There's nothing in LaTeX that requires `\includegraphics` to be in a `figure` environment.

Comment: Because OP's MWE had a figure environment?

Comment: Well, why perpetuate the error?

Comment: Then I want to be educated. Why is it an error to include a graphics in a figure environment?

Comment: It's not an error *per se*; but in this case it is not a float, since you want the picture exactly there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [titling-package](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf) for this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{titling}

\title{...}
\author{...}


\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{logo.pdf} 
}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this code is some a little problem. It seems to work, but instead figure, there is black box. :/

Comment: @user3421673: remove `[demo]` then

Comment: Doesn't work. It jumped again on new page

Comment: It jumps on a new page if the image is to big. Does \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{logo.pdf} work?

Comment: Yes it works, but I don't think, that width=1.0 is too big. Theres is a lot of place.

Comment: Please upload the logo.pdf file.

Comment: \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=0.65\textheight]{PAKDIST}

Comment: you should try to reduce width and height of your gaphics by using abov command, use your graphics name instead of PAKDIST

Comment: also the code uploaded by SLx64is working well